# jQuery :visible filter not working as I expect it (Emphasis on 'I')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a setup like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="innercont">
     <ul>
       <li><img src="frame1.jpg"></li>
       <li><img src="frame2.jpg"></li>
       <li><img src="frame3.jpg"></li>
       <li><img src="frame4.jpg"></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Container is 100px wide, innercont is 400px wide, the images are 100px wide and LI's are floated left, and I'm using controls and jQuery to shift the position of innercont to 'reveal' the frames.

My goal was to get the 'height' of the frame that was visible. This is the code I'm using:

```
height = jQuery("#innercont ul").children("li").filter(':visible').css('height');
```

But I always get the height of the first image regardless of which one is visible.  Am I just daft?

Comment: Visible is to detect if something takes up space in the document, not if it is out of view. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

Comment: what about their visibilty in csss are they hidden ?

Comment: `height:0`, `width:0`, `display:none` would all be "invisible" otherwise, `:visible` will pick it up.

Comment: @M.chaudhry - `visibility: hidden` counts as visible since it takes up space.

Comment: Ah thanks guys, I've found a different solution and now understand :visible.